# How namespaces load classes at runtime

Tags: c#

What happens at runtime when number of namespaces are used in the program? Are the classes from the namespaces loaded entirely or the class used in program get loaded? What if there are unused namespaces present in the program?

Comment: Namespaces don't _load_ classes. Namespaces organize class names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Namespaces are really more of a compile time construct then a runtime construct.  Putting classes into a namespace primarily only affects the name of the class.  The "fully qualified name" of any class is actually its namespace hierarchy(separated by periods `.`) followed by the actual class name.  You con't "load" a namespace at runtime, the entire concept doesn't exist.

When you compile a program, if you compile it to a library (.dll) you can add a reference to that .dll, in which case all of the classes in that dll are "accessibe" in your program.  As for whether they'll be loaded, it's certainly *possible* for them to be loaded, but chances are due to lazy initialization unused classes won't have a significant impact on performance.

When you add a `using` statement to the top of a file for a namespace, it doesn't "load" that namespace.  It will be used by the compiler to resolve all "unqualified" class names to "fully qualified" class names (at compile time).  If you used just fully qualified class names in the first place you wouldn't need any `using`s (but that *really* clutters up your code, so you should add them anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You can `use` as many namespaces as you like. Namespaces do not load classes. Think of namespaces as a convenience feature, kind of like a `path` variable. If you don't use namespaces, you'd end up writing code like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> myList = 
    new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
```

This would make code writing extremely wordy and tedious in short order. By `using` namespaces, you could shorten the code to this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

// ..... further down in code:
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

The following 2 links might help expand your understanding of namespaces:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Bottom line: `namespaces` help organize and control the scope of visibility for your classes in the project.

HTH...