# Allowing use of Array without "using System"

Tags: c#, arrays

Simple question.
Before i can use the "Array." in my script i need to import this function somehow. This can be done through  "using system;", but I have understood that it is bad to import entire libraries like that.
So, exactly what library is Array a part of? 
(I understand that this can be found instantly by googling if you know what to search for, but the searches I have made gave no result .)

Comment: What language are you using? Please add appropriate tag.

Comment: In every language I'm aware of that has it, the `using` keyword doesn't "import" a library, it just extends the local namespace to allow more concise references.

Comment: it's C#. Sorry for late response.

Comment: A `using` directive doesn't "import an entire library". It's just making a namespace available (the `System` namespace). What concrete downside are you expecting from that?

Comment: What script? What code? Show an example. For the most part, you don't even need the Array class directly.

Comment: I am trying to use "Array.IndexOf(TestList, "Test StringTo Be Found");". Without the line "using System;", this line returns error: "the name array does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @gelbrekt it returns that error because you need that using statement or you have to fully qualify the name, ex: System.Array. You have to do one of those so the compiler knows you're talking about System.Array and not some type called Array declared in some other namespace. Of course, no good programmer should make their own Array class since it would clearly clash. But what about two third party libraries that both have a type with the same name? Specifying the namespace in either of the mentioned ways helps the compiler know which you actually intend to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have understood that it is bad to import entire libraries like that.

You are not "importing" a library in the sense of linking code - you are just telling the compiler to search that *namespace* to resolve and names that it can't find in the current namespace.  There's no difference to the compiled code whether or not the `using` is used. Meaning that the following are equivalent:

```
using System;

....
    index i = Array.IndexOf(TestList, "Test StringTo Be Found");
```

and:

```
    index i = System.Array.IndexOf(TestList, "Test StringTo Be Found");
```

compile to the exact same IL code. So if you can't supply the `using` directive, then just prepend `Array` with the namespace.

The only danger is name collisions if the current namespace has types with the same name as types within the `system` namespace, which should be very rare (and you'd get a compiler warning in that case).

You could also reference the array class as `System.Array` - the `using` directive just lets you reference the `Array` class without prepending the `System` namespace.

> So, exactly what library is Array a part of?

The [`Array` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) is found in the mscorlib.dll *assembly*.

Comment: I don't quite understand. You say that there is no difference to the code wherter the "using System" is used or not. But the program returns an error if that line isn't used. Also, the line "using System.Array" does not work. it returns the error: "A 'using namespace' directive can only be applies to namespaces"

Comment: `System.Array.IndexOf(TestList, "Test StringTo Be Found");` @gelbrekt

Comment: Yes, thank you! That worked. But is there a way to shorten that down so that only Array has to be written? (Such as the python syntax "import as" - like "Use System.Array" as "Array".)

Comment: @gelbrekt are you saying that you can't use `using` because you're inserting code somewhere outside of a namespace? If so then you _have_ to supply the namespace.  See my edit for what I mean by "there is no difference"

Comment: [Better read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace-keywords). @gelbrekt

Comment: @D Stanley I'm not so sure the two lines you have there are equivalent. I use c# in Unity, and the preloaded "using references" in Unity are System.Collections; and System.Collections.Generic;. If i have understood it correctly, they could just have written "Using system" instead of those lines. But surely the reason why this isn't done is because of preformance. My guess is that the preformance gets significantly better when having the System.Collections; and System.Collections.Generic lines in the code, rather than replacing these with "using System;": Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Yes, my assumption was correct, partly at least. The lines "using System.Collections;" and ""using System.Collections.Generic;" can be replaced by "using System". So why is that each project created in unity starts with these 2 lines rater than the generalised "using System"?

Comment: @gelbrekt In C#, unlike Java, using a namespace does NOT include all of its child namespaces.  When you "use" a namespace, you are using _that namespace only_. So your assertion that "using System.Collections;" and "using System.Collections.Generic;" can be replaced by "using System" is false.  `using` is a compile-time construct only.  It makes no difference in the compiled code, so would have no performance impact whatsoever.

Comment: Sounds reasonable i guess. However, Visual Studio suggests "Namespace system Using directive is unnecessary" and "remove unnecessary usings" on those two lines when the line "using System"  is there. Are you really sure that what you are saying applies to c#?

Comment: @gelbrekt From [the documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive): "A `using` directive does not give you access to any namespaces that are nested in the namespace you specify. " I suspect that either you're not using any types in those namespaces or Unity is doing something else that makes them unnecessary.

Comment: You now the difference beetween a reference and a `using`? [When you add a `using` statement to the top of a file for a namespace, it doesn't "load" that namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13234969/2441442) @gelbrekt

Comment: @gelbrekt Are you really questioning a high experienced user about their knowledge of basic C#? There is no performance difference. You can try and measure. The reason VS suggests to remove the using statements has nothing to do with performance: it's to remove clutter from the code. If you're not using it, don't bother having it. But if you're going to use a type from that namespace, it probably makes sense to add the usings so you don't have to use the fully qualified type name everywhere (System.Array). Imagine if every type was always fully qualified in the code. It'd be ugly code.

Comment: Alright, manson you are right. I see now that I was wrong and that there is no preformance difference. Thank you for your help!